# Implementing General Tree

Tags: c++, class, object, tree, oop

I came across the following code and despite some help from others, I am still having trouble understanding it. 
This code is supposed to implement a General Tree. Single_List and Single_Node classes are also available for use in implementation.

```
        template <class Object>
        class General_tree {
            private:
                Object element;  // the stored in the node
                Single_list< General_tree<Object> * > children;
                    // a linked list of pointers to general trees
            public:
                Object retrieve() {
                    return element;
                }
                // ...
        };
```

Can someone tell me what one instance of this class will consist of?

I think it will consist of

```
                           [element value in node made by Single_Node] -----> 
                             /                           next pointer (part of Single_list class)
                            / 
                           / children pointer to another such instance of General_Tree
                          V
```

Then these instances can be combined to form a tree... I am still getting used to Object Oriented Design I guess so please let me know if this reasoning and interpretation is correct?

thanks!

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a "next pointer".

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/property_tree.html is worth a look if you want to do something like this in some real (non training) code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tree object is really a node in the tree, where `children` points to the nodes at the next level, which will have pointers to **their** children, etc.

Together they form a subtree (or the whole tree, if it is the root node).

Comment: Thanks, your response is very clear and well written. Just to clear this up: when you say "nodes" at the next level, do you mean one singular node at the next level. So the children pointer of one instance points to ONE appropriate node at the next level right?

Comment: @rrazd - The `children` is a list of pointers, each presumably pointing to one child. Because it is a list, you can have a varying number of nodes at the next level, just like real tree branches.

Comment: So to add multiple child nodes within one instance you would just use push_front() function in Single_List class? Thus the children pointer will be the head pointer of the linked list? These nodes generated for push_front will be of the General Tree Pointer type thus they too will have children pointers....is this correct?

Comment: Also, if possible can you do a quick ascii drawing of the most basic instance possible for the class? I think it will help me with the visualization. Thanks a lot for your help.